# WebPartManager & Mobile Controls

Tags: asp.net, mobile

Can WebPartManager be used with web parts constructed from mobile web controls?  If possible, should it be done?

Answer (score 0):

I looks promising and you just have to tried it out. In mobile development you always need to have full control of the generated output, and this looks like a tool to do a part of the job.

But remember many devices have issues of their own, so you need to be able to control every part of your output. So far I have not come accros any framework that was suitable for the job.